# How to customized Ag grid react pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, ag-grid-react

How to customized Ag grid react pagination, I am using shared documentation below code.

```
  <AgGridReact
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          suppressRowClickSelection={true}
          groupSelectsChildren={true}
          rowSelection={'multiple'}
          pivotPanelShow={'always'}
          pagination={true}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
        />
```

it is displaying default pagination in bottom  after all rows
it is display

```
1 to 10 of 100 |< <page 1 of 10> >|
```

but I want per page number user can select using dropdown
i want drop down and inside dropdown like 10,20,30......

so my custom pagination  be look like

```
 page 10 inside dropdown 1-10 of 100 < >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a select box over your AgGridReact component and attach an event listener to it for the desired result.

select element

```
<div style={{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}}>
  Page Size:
  <select onChange={onPageSizeChanged} id="page-size">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
  <AgGridReact
    rowData={rowData}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    suppressRowClickSelection={true}
    groupSelectsChildren={true}
    rowSelection={'multiple'}
    rowGroupPanelShow={'always'}
    pivotPanelShow={'always'}
    pagination={true}
    paginationPageSize={10}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
  />
</div>
```

event listener

```
const onPageSizeChanged = useCallback(() => {
  var value = document.getElementById('page-size').value;
  gridRef.current.api.paginationSetPageSize(Number(value));
}, []);
```

**Result**
[image: Result]

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/wBzFQeiTpPNtkoMH?preview